# asp net mvc: Model is not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a page with a few text boxes. I edit/input some values in these text boxes and click on a button, but my model is not updated (I see old values in alert). How can I fix it?

```
@model MyModel

<div class="text-center">      
    <form >
        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Property)
        }

        <input id="btnFormAjaxJson" type="button" value="Save" />

    </form>
</div>

@section scripts{

    <script>
    $('#btnFormAjaxJson').on('click', function () {
 
    
    var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model));

    alert(JSON.stringify(json));

    $.ajax({
    url: '/api/Home',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(json)
    }).done(function (result) {
    alert(result.FullName)
    });
 
    });
      </script>
}
```

Comment: Because your form does not have `action`  attribute, maybe you can use `@Html` helper to help you to produce form?

Comment: @HsuTingHuan I want to send api request

Comment: Then you need share your `/api/Home`'s code too. If your ajax works fine, the problem maybe is on the server side

Comment: Actually I don't find any error in your code, Have you debuged it to check if `/api/Home` can receive the value successfully?